# Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

When proving that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

> Let $G = \langle a \rangle$ and suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and assume that $H \ne \{e\}  $.

The author begins with the *claim* that $H$ contains an element of the form $a^{t}$, where $t$ is positive.

To verify this claim, he says,

> Since $G = \langle a \rangle$, every element of H has the form $a^{t}$; and when $a^{t}$ belongs to $H$ with $t<0$, then $a^{-t}$ belongs to $H$ also and -t is positive.

I see the first part clearly, but I am not able to see clearly what the second part which begin after ';' is saying.

Comment: Isnt he using the fact that its inverse must be in the subgroup $H$ ?

Comment: yes wow good. But why is he mentioning negative integers when he could have simply used the property of inverse in a subgroup, and completely altering the statement?

Comment: I belive the answer below will help you with that , at first he doenst know what type of element is there he just knows that there is one, so he has to assume it could have a negative or positive exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, suppose you choose an arbitrary element $p$ from the subgroup $H$. Then as the elements of $H$ are also the elements of the group $G=<a>$ then p is of the form $a^t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. If this $t$ is positive then we are done but if $t\lt0$ then H being the subgroup $a^{-t} \in H$ and $-t\gt0$. So in any case we have $a^s \in H$ for $s\gt0$.

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that $G=\langle a\rangle$ means that$$G=\{a^t\mid t\in\Bbb Z\}.$$So, the author has to assume that an element of $H$ may be of the form $a^t$, with $t<0$.

Comment: i don't follow, sir.

Comment: By that definition, if $a^t\in H$, $t$ may be reater than or smaller than $0$. But if $a^t\in H$ with $t<0$, then its inverse belongs to $H$ too. And the inverse of $a^t$ is $a^{-t}$. Now, since t«$t<0$, $-t>0$. So, this proves that for some $t\in\Bbb N$, $a^t\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that WLOG we may assume any $g\in H$ is of the form $g=h^t$ for some $t\in\Bbb Z^+$, just by using the fact that when $a$ generates, so does $a^{-1}$.